# Has anyone tried to use javax.persistence on Android?

Tags: android, persistence

Has anyone tried to use javax.persistence on Android by getting the source or jar and adding it to their project?

Answer (score 2):

Odds are, you will not be able to add the JAR or source. The Android build tools actively block you from importing much in the `java.*` and `javax.*` packages.

If Apache Harmony has an implementation of `javax.persistence`, and you are willing to refactor it to a new package (e.g., via `jarjar`), you can give it a try.